# Как продолжить цикл foreach после следующего обращения к скрипту?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

```
$a = 9; #Задаём, сколько элементов массива должен обработать foreach
foreach () { #Запускаем цикл
     #Выполняется код
     $a--; #Вычитаем из a по единице за каждый обработанный элемент массива
     if ($a < 1) break; #Останавливаем foreach когда а достигает значения 0
}
```

Мне нужен код, который позволит продолжить цикл по нажатию на какой-либо div. То есть код выше сгенерировал 9 элементов, и мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию клавиши цикл продолжил генерировать элементы из массива с 10 и до конца
Или же начал код с нуля выполнять, только без переменной и break, как удобней будет это реализовать

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Для решения проблемы всего лишь нужно добавить второй цикл, но с параметром array_slice

```
include; #Достаём массив
$a = 9; #Задаём, сколько элементов массива должен обработать foreach
foreach ($b as $c) { #Запускаем цикл
     #Выполняется код
     $a--; #Вычитаем из a по единице за каждый обработанный элемент массива
     if ($a < 1) break; #Останавливаем foreach когда а достигает значения 0
};
include; #Вновь достаём массив
foreach (array_slice($b, 9) as $c) { #Запускаем цикл от заданного элемента массива
     #Выполняется код
};
```

А как реализовать продолжение цикла по нажатию на div? Через функцию и команду GET

```
include; #Достаём массив
    $a = 9; #Задаём, сколько элементов массива должен обработать foreach
    foreach ($b as $c) { #Запускаем цикл
         #Выполняется код
         $a--; #Вычитаем из a по единице за каждый обработанный элемент массива
         if ($a < 1) break; #Останавливаем foreach когда а достигает значения 0
    };
function d() {
    include; #Вновь достаём массив
    foreach (array_slice($b, 9) as $c) { #Запускаем цикл от заданного элемента массива
          #Выполняется код
    };
};
if (isset($_GET['e'])) { #Задаём GET для дальнейшего применения
    d();
};
```

А дальше вставляем название GET-запроса в div, дабы вторая часть цикла, завёрнутая в функцию, выполнялась по нажатию на div. Вопросительный знак перед названием запроса прописывать обязательно

```
<a href="?e">Название ссылки</a>
```

Comment: в этом случае непонятно, что мешало использовать array_slice и в первом цикле :)

Comment: То, что я не знал о нём?

Comment: ну вот сейчас вы про неё знаете, но все равно колупаетесь со счетчиком :)

Comment: Но главное, судя по коду, при нажатии на ссылку у вас выводятся все картинки. То есть первая часть массива  выводится два раза. Отличная экономия трафика :)))

Comment: Вы так активность набиваете на сайте, или что?

Comment: Я просто пытаюсь вам намекнуть, что с таким трудом найденное вами решение, возможно, не является оптимальным :)

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам надо разобраться с тем, [как работает РНР](https://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke).

И уяснить, что **продолжить**, "после нажатия на div", никакой цикл **невозможно в принципе**. Тот цикл давно тю-тю. Завершился, причем вместе со всем РНР скриптом.

Чтобы продолжить скрипт во время **следующего** выполнения скрипта, надо добавить ещё одну переменную, $b. И точно так же вычитать из неё, но только делая не `break`, а `continue`, в самом начале цикла. И значение для этой переменной передавать, соответственно, из браузера.

Правда, **исходную задачу**, которую и надо было описывать в вопросе, без всех этих foreach и break, куда проще решить на стороне браузера. Собственно, и сам вопрос надо было задавать под тегом CSS, а не РНР.

По достижении нужной цифры цикл не останавливать а заключить оставшиеся элементы в тот самый див с display: none. Который потом по клику и открывать.

Comment: А при display: none изображения не будут подгружаться и жрать трафик пользователя?

Comment: И как с помощью continue пропустить девять элементов массива и сразу начать с десятого?

Comment: Будут разумеется. У вас в вопросе ничего про изображения не было. Если надо экономить трафик, то делать первым способом. пропустить девять элементов массива и сразу начать с десятого  с помощью continue **точно так же**, как и перестать выводить после девятого с помощью break. Вот абсолютно идентичный код.

Comment: Так а как пропустить девять элементов массива с помощью continue? Я документацию читаю и не могу понять

Comment: Показывайте, как пытаетесь. Я не понимаю, что там может быть непонятно. [Вот ваш набросок](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/e2d32cc5b6107bbb86b5419789a92b12/). Добавляйте в него тестовый массив, делайте код рабочим и показывайте, как вы добавляете continue.

Comment: А можно просто готовый кусок решения, а не предложение идти долбаться дальше самостоятельно? Я не за этим с вопросом сюда пришёл

Comment: Ну та к вы сюда пришли не по адресу. Здесь не бесплатный сервис по написанию кода для всех желающих.